# which vcs tracks change comments per file

Tags: version-control, mercurial

We need to change to a new VCS system. I can't seem to find one that tracks change comments both per file and per change-set. Currently when we view file history in our present VCS it shows the various check-ins and the comments for the file on that check in and the over-all check-in comment. We are currently evaluating hg and like it, but can't find how to implement this behavior. Can anyone suggest how to do it in hg - or what VCS would allow this feature? Thanks so much.

Comment: Why do you need per-file commit comments, *in addition to* per-changeset comment? Wouldn't changeset comment suffice?

Comment: Its what we're used to and has been very convenient when looking at file history for us. Our way of working makes good use of it, that's all. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to see the comments embedded in each source file, as you might see if you'd used the `$Log$` keyword in `rcs`?

Comment: The comments don't need to be saved in the source file -just associated with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
$ hg log your-file
```

with Mercurial to get the history of just that file. It also works for directories or multiple files where you get a log of changesets changing either of the specified files.

Mercurial is actually very efficient for this: despite having repository-wide changesets, it stores the deltas on a per-file basis and this makes it very easy for Mercurial to show you the per-file history.

Comment: Does this allow my comments for each file? I glanced at the docs and it appears to be the normal hg generated for each file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You decide which files go into each commit (with `hg commit foo.c bar.h`) and `hg log foo.c` will then show you commits involving `foo.c` afterwards. So you don't "comment on files", you comment on a commit and can later see the relevant comments on a per-file basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hg's `commit` works on either the changed files you specify or all the files that it finds have changed.  That group of files then makes up the changeset and the same commit message will then be applied all.  It sounds like you are looking for a super commit to wrap several commits into one bigger commit.

Named branches are the intended method for something like this.  You can then have commits with comments that are specific to certain files and the overall branch name is the feature you are grouping together.  Through the command line or Tortoise Hg you can select what files are part of each commit.